# Nuget Package Error during Installation of MongoDB driver

Tags: c#, mongodb

I am Working on Visual Studio 2015 and installed nuget (VS 2015 VSIX - latest (v3.4.1)) then executed below mentioned command but getting error.

Install-Package MongoDB.Bson
Install-Package : Unable to find package 'MongoDB.Bson'
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-Package MongoDB.Bson
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried just using the gui to search for and install the package you want?

[image: Example]

Comment: yes I tried in a console application, all commands are running properly but with same process when i am choosing C# script in SSIS, it is giving same error.

Comment: glad to help - if this answered your question please remember to mark it as the answer.